# Updating a table row with random number fails

Tags: mysql

I am using a while loop in a stored procedure to update each row of my table but the update value remains the same for all rows.For instance,in my table the generated number is 2266 for all rows instead of a unique digit.

My stored procedure looks like this

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE lesrows()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE lesrand INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students INTO n;
select(FLOOR(2000 + RAND() * (3000 - 2000) )) into lesrand;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
  UPDATE students set student_number= lesrand;
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
End;
;;

call lesrows();
```

Why is it inserting a constant number for all rows instead of a unique number for every row?.

Comment: The while statement sets the whole table's student_number's the lesrand on every single iteration. You want a new random number of each iteration (inside the loop) and you want to select students one-by-one using WHERE with your variable i.

Comment: I want a new random number for each iteration.

Comment: @danihp I have done it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The while statement sets the whole table's student_number's the lesrand on every single iteration. You want a new random number of each iteration (inside the loop) and you want to select students one-by-one using WHERE with your variable i

Something like this:

```
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
select(FLOOR(2000 + RAND() * (3000 - 2000) )) into lesrand;      
UPDATE students set student_number= lesrand WHERE student_ID = i;
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
```

Comment: Still the same result with your suggestion `BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE lesrand INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
select(FLOOR(2000 + RAND() * (3000 - 2000) )) into lesrand;      
UPDATE students set student_number= lesrand WHERE student_ID = i;
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
End`

Comment: well student_ID was a guess at your table design. What is the primary key? you need to use i to somehow iterate over the students (i.e. mapping i to the primary key somehow). Also on a separate matter - why (3000-2000)? why not 1000?

Comment: You are in luck,student_id is the primary key.

Comment: @danihp I've been out of SO for a while. good to see supportive people around. thanks, mate.

Comment: OK well make sure the case is right. I used upper case. Did you try using lower case?

Comment: Here is the schema for the `students` table `CREATE TABLE `students` (
 `student_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `student_names` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 `student_number` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1212;`

Comment: Ok, seems to me like it should work providing that you are not deleting students from the start of the list - and that the column names line up with those in the procedure.

Comment: That is correct.It now works.But i can't help what if i wanted this procedure for non-sequential rows of data,without the help of a cursor which won't work here,this will be impossible.

Comment: Yes for that I would personally create a temp table with the IDs of student table (e.g.) and give that table a sequential primary key. Then iterate over the temp table taking the IDs from the student table and updating based on that. Otherwise I'd use PHP or something for easier iteration. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but it looks like lesrand is only assigned once. Have you tried moving `select(FLOOR(2000 + RAND() * (3000 - 2000) )) into lesrand;` into the while loop like this:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE lesrows()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE lesrand INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
  select(FLOOR(2000 + RAND() * (3000 - 2000) )) into lesrand;
  UPDATE students set student_number= lesrand;
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
End;
;;

call lesrows();
```

And why are you using a stored procedure. Wouldn't `UPDATE students SET student_number = FLOOR(2000 + RAND() * (3000 - 2000))` have the same result?

Comment: This will still set the whole table's student_number to the random number on each iteration. So the last random number will be assigned to them all.

Comment: Idiot might be a bit extreme. All the best, buddy